# how can set substr for special chars?

Tags: php, substr, htmlspecialchars

how can I `substr` a text that execute `htmlspecialchars` to it.

**saved in database**

```
some text &quot; some text &quot; some text
&#039; some text &#039; some text &#039;some text&#039; some text &#039;
some text &#039;some text &#039; some text &#039; some text &#039;
```

**with htmlspecialchars ( I want to `substr` from this text )**

```
some text " some text " some text ' some text ' some text ' some text '
some text ' some text ' some text ' some text ' some text '
```

**when substr :**

```
some text " some text " some text ' some text �
```

Tanks

**UPDATE**

I use this

```
 if( strlen($text)>100){
    $s = html_entity_decode($text);
    $shorten = substr($s,0,50);
    echo htmlentities($shorten);
  }
```

and just changes `&quot;`

Comment: Have you tried to decode the string with the special chars?

Comment: yeah, I did ,but didn't work

Comment: Then I think you need to show us the code, tell us what happens and what _exactly_ you want to happen.

Comment: @Simon using `html_entity_decode` ?

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: You just found one of the reasons to never save HTML encoded strings in the database. Try to avoid that and escape just before output

Comment: problem was 'ENT_QUOTES'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) before substr and [encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) after:

```
$str = htmlentities(
   substr(html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES),0,50)
,ENT_QUOTES);
```

[Test at eval.in](https://eval.in/280275) (*link expires soon*)